# What is wrong with my loops?

Tags: java, loops

So I'm trying to "optimize" my code, by reducing the number of lines, by using lots of loops. But it's been.....problematic.

I'm just trying to display a bunch of radio buttons, only two buttons appear and neither do anything.

Just wondered if someone could critique my code and show this newb where he is going wrong.

Grateful for any help :)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;


public class NewGame implements ActionListener {

    private final String[] premierLeagueClubs = {"Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace",
        "Everton", "Hull City", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester United", "Manchester City", "Middlesborough",
        "Southampton", "Stoke City", "Sunderland", "Swansea City", "Tottenham Hotspur", "Watford", "West Brom", "West Ham"};
    private final JRadioButton[] rb = new JRadioButton[20];
    JFrame f3;
    private final JButton b, quit;
    String teamName;
    JLabel label1;
    private static JPanel chooseClubPanel;

    public NewGame() {
        f3 = new JFrame("Ballon d'or");
        f3.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f3.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        chooseClubPanel = new JPanel();
        f3.add(chooseClubPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        chooseClubPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        label1 = new JLabel("Please choose a team");
        chooseClubPanel.add(label1);

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        int startvalueBG;
        int endvalueBG = 19;
        for (startvalueBG = 0; startvalueBG <= endvalueBG; startvalueBG++) {
            bg.add(rb[startvalueBG]);
        }

        b = new JButton("OK");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        chooseClubPanel.add(b);

        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        chooseClubPanel.add(quit);

        int startValueAddRB;
        int endValueAddRB = 19;
        for (startValueAddRB = 0; startValueAddRB <= endValueAddRB; startValueAddRB++) {
            f3.add(rb[startValueAddRB]);
        }

        int startRB;
        int endRB = 19;

        for (startRB = 0; endRB <= 19; startRB++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < premierLeagueClubs.length; i++) {
                rb[startRB] = new JRadioButton(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
                chooseClubPanel.add(rb[i]);
            }
        }
        f3.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f3, "Are you sure ?", "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    f3.setVisible(false);
                    f3.dispose();
                } else {

                    f3.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setFrame(JFrame f3) {
        this.f3 = f3;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {

        return f3;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int rbNumber;
        int rbNumberMax = 19;

        for (rbNumber = 0; rbNumber < rbNumberMax; rbNumber++) {
            if (rb[rbNumber].isSelected()) {
                teamName = rb[rbNumber].getText();
                f3.dispose();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f3, "You chose : " + rb[rbNumber].getText());

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Based on the sample code you've provided, you're going to hit a `NullPointerException` as `rb` doesn't actually contain anything

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that, but I am more interested in the logic of my loops. The radio buttons are not appearing in my gui. I can get them to appear if if I write each line individually, so I think it's the logic of my loop. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you actually add any of the buttons to the container?

Comment: Yes, if I add them line by line, the radio buttons appear in my gui. However, rather than writing 20 lines of code, it made sense to try a for loop. This piece of code is supposed to add the radio buttons to my JPanel and yes the JPanel is added to my JFrame.

Comment: for (startRB = 0; endRB <= 19; startRB++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < premierLeagueClubs.length; i++) {
                rb[startRB] = new JRadioButton(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
                chooseClubPanel.add(rb[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's take a look at the code...

First, you try and add each button to the `ButtonGroup`, but, you've not actually created any yet, possible `NullPointerException`

```
int startvalueBG;
int endvalueBG = 19;
for (startvalueBG = 0; startvalueBG <= endvalueBG; startvalueBG++) {
    bg.add(rb[startvalueBG]);
}

b = new JButton("OK");
b.addActionListener(this);
chooseClubPanel.add(b);

quit = new JButton("Quit");
quit.addActionListener(this);
chooseClubPanel.add(quit);
```

Then you add each button to the frame, but, the frame is using a `BorderLayout`, so only one button will remain visible, the last one you added...

```
int startValueAddRB;
int endValueAddRB = 19;
for (startValueAddRB = 0; startValueAddRB <= endValueAddRB; startValueAddRB++) {
    f3.add(rb[startValueAddRB]);
}
```

Then you try and add the buttons to `chooseClubPanel`, effectively removing the from the frame, but the indices are all messed up, you are creating 19x19 buttons, each club is assigned to all 19 and the effectively replace by the next club...!?!?

```
int startRB;
int endRB = 19;

for (startRB = 0; endRB <= 19; startRB++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < premierLeagueClubs.length; i++) {
        rb[startRB] = new JRadioButton(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
        chooseClubPanel.add(rb[i]);
    }
}
```

The first thing we're going to do is remove the reference to the frame `chooseClubPanel`, they're just getting in the way and the class has no business generating the frame, that's not it's responsibility.

Next, we're going to make `NewGame` a `JPanel` and allow it to become self managing.

Next, we're going to reduce the number of loops from 3 to 1 and do all the work we need to do all at the same time

[image: Teams]

```
public class NewGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final String[] premierLeagueClubs = {"Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace",
                                                                                             "Everton", "Hull City", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester United", "Manchester City", "Middlesborough",
                                                                                             "Southampton", "Stoke City", "Sunderland", "Swansea City", "Tottenham Hotspur", "Watford", "West Brom", "West Ham"};
    private final JRadioButton[] rb = new JRadioButton[20];
    private final JButton b, quit;
    String teamName;
    JLabel label1;

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

    public NewGame() {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        label1 = new JLabel("Please choose a team");
        add(label1);

        for (int i = 0; i < premierLeagueClubs.length; i++) {
            rb[i] = new JRadioButton(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
            rb[i].setActionCommand(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
            bg.add(rb[i]);
            add(rb[i]);
        }

        b = new JButton("OK");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);

        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        add(quit);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You have selected " + bg.getSelection().getActionCommand());
    }

}
```

At some point you're going to want to display, the simplest solution is to just add it whatever container you want, like a `JFrame`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new NewGame());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Normally I suggest having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) but in your case, I think it would be more pratical to have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, it's given me a lot of think about. In particular, I am going to explore the concept of only having one JFrame and extending JPanel as you have, for my other classes. My JFrames don't appear quickly, I am creating a JFrame, do stuff, then use the dispose() method to remove the JFrame and repeat this process several times. It works, but even this newb can see that it's far from ideal. Thanks for your feedback :)